# Display the http stream of my ip cameras on my web page

Tags: python, authentication, hash, proxy

On my raspberry I installed a web server (apache, html5, javascript), the pages are generated in python.
I would like to be able to display the HTTP stream (http://192.168.20.124/mjpeg/stream.cgi?chn=0) of my IP cameras on my site.
These require Digest authentication.
How to display this feed without having to enter the user/password of the cameras in my app.
I would like my app to authenticate itself automatically.
I have tried different python modules which

1. allowed Digest authentication
2. launches a proxy or reverse proxy server

They work individually but I can't get them to work together.

Thank you for your ideas and solutions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: is this link to stream or to page which displays stream? Some servers allow `http://user:password@ip_address/...` and then you can use it in `<img scr="...">` but this way everyone can see password in HTML. If you would run Python web framework `Flask` then you could try to create generator which read stream from camera and gives access to this stream with own URL. There are examples how to read frames from normal webcam on Raspberry Pi using generator in Flask - but it doesn't use authentication.

Comment: [Video Streaming with Flask - miguelgrinberg.com](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask)